# Understanding derivation of Hessian Sketch formula

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

I've been reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.0347.pdf) and in equation 23 they ask us to consider the optimization problem.
\begin{align}
\hat{u} = \arg \min_{u \in C - x^t} \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \lVert Au \rVert^2_2 - \langle A^T(y-Ax^t), u\rangle \right\}
\end{align}

where $x^t$ is iterate at step $t$, $A$ is $n\times p$ data matrix, $y$ is $n\times 1$ and $C$ is our feasible region.
The claim is that $\hat{u} = x^{LS} - x^t$ where $x^{LS}$ is the least squares solution to $Ax^{LS} = y$.

Would someone be able to guide me through how the authors got this result?

Comment: Quite an interesting paper you're reading. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the gradient of the objective function yields
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{u}}
=
\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{Au} -
\mathbf{A}^T (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}^{[t]})
=
\mathbf{A}^T
\left[
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{x}^{[t]})
-
\mathbf{y}
\right]
$$
The gradient is null iff
$$
\mathbf{u}
=
\mathbf{x}_{LS}
-
\mathbf{x}^{[t]}
$$